# Linking an entry in a TextField to a randomly generated number?

Tags: java, swing, random

I'm trying to make a program that is similar to Quizlet. A guessing game basically.
I'm confused as to how I would do or even approach this.

I want a program where a random Number is generated in one TextField (which I have done), and the number that is generated is assigned to a string. I have made a list of characters and actions which should be assigned to any number between 1 and 50. So when the randomly generated number shows, the player would have to guess which character or action the number shown is associated with. There's a TextField below it where you guess.

```
   public class NumberSide {



public NumberSide(){

frame();

}

public void frame(){


JFrame f2 = new JFrame();
f2.setVisible(true); //Set Visible
f2.setSize(600,400); //Set Size
f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Add Close Function


JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); //Create Panel
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
p2.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
//Code for Panel below.
f2.add(p2); //Add panel to frame.


JLabel TextAssigned = new JLabel();
//Code for Text Assigned below
TextAssigned.setText("What Character/Action is assigned with the number above?");
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 2;
TextAssigned.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
p2.add(TextAssigned, gbc);


JTextField RandomNumber = new JTextField();
//Code for randum number below.
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 1;
Random rn = new Random();
RandomNumber.setText(Integer.toString(rn.nextInt(51)));
RandomNumber.setEditable(false);
RandomNumber.setFont(new Font("Sans serif", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 60));
RandomNumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  

    //Code for function goes here.  

    }}); 
p2.add(RandomNumber, gbc); //Adding to the panel, after done with all functions. 


JTextField AnswerBox = new JTextField();
//Code for Answer Box below.
AnswerBox.setSize(100,100);
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 4;
AnswerBox.requestFocus(true);
AnswerBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                       

    //Code for function goes here.        

    }}); 
AnswerBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (100,30)); //Set Dimensions
p2.add(AnswerBox, gbc); //Add Text Field to panel


JButton OK = new JButton("Ok");
//Code for OK Button below.
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 5;
OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                       

    //Code for function goes here.
    RandomNumber.setText(Integer.toString(rn.nextInt(51)));
    String input = AnswerBox.getText();


    }});    
p2.add(OK, gbc);


JButton Quit = new JButton("Quit");
//Code for Quit Button below.
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 9;  
Quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    //Code for function goes here.
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                       
    System.exit(0);           
    }});    
p2.add(Quit, gbc);//Adding to the panel, after done with all functions. 


}

}
```

How would I go about doing this? Here's my GUI...

[image: GUI]!

Comment: What question are you asking exactly? Are you try to get the text that the user enters into the text box?

Comment: @thepure12 noo im trying to get the text that is entered into the textfield, to link to the number generated. So when the OK button is pressed, depending on whether he guessed correct or not, it would show the results. Just linking the answer box to the randomly generated number.

Comment: In you `ActionListener` check the values of the fields and take appropriate actions based on their matches